# Forward messages in Smack 4.1 XMPP android?

Tags: android

i want to add forward feature to my chat app which is developed using Smack 4.1. what are the steps to follow.?Please help

Comment: Did you mean deliverd report?

Comment: no, forwarding user A message to User B. there should be some way to specify a message is forwarded .

Comment: we need to add ExtensionElements with Element Name and NameScape. I want some example link. I found for parsing incoming message but how can i add ExtensionElements to outgoing message?